# Run-time error for dynamic order-by clause (static equivalent clause works)

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, abap, dynamic-sql

The question is if there is any other checks triggered for dynamic order-by clauses than for hardcoded order-by clauses in abap.

I wrote in abap a sql statement. This statement sums up the counts of entries for specific years. Then it groups the count based on the type of the entry.
After that I tried to do a dynamic sorting. For some reason this leads to an error: "The parser produced the error: The expression that contains IN_YEAR is not a GROUP-BY expression."

The thing is that the order-by clause is working when hardcoding the sort criteria. When I try to do it dynamically it does not.

But I have to do the sorting dynamically because later the sort criteria will come from the frontend via oData (it_order).

```
DATA:    lv_cYear      TYPE NUMC4,
         lv_lYear      TYPE NUMC4,
         lv_2YearsAgo  TYPE NUMC4,

         lv_order_by   TYPE string.

GET TIME.
lv_cYear = sy-datum+0(4).
LV_LYEAR = LV_CYEAR - 1.
LV_2YEARSAGO = LV_CYEAR - 2.

*later lv_order_by should be filled dynamically
lv_order_by = 'RRC2019 DESCENDING, RRC2018 DESCENDING'.    

SELECT      
   type_name AS type,
   SUM( CASE WHEN in_year eq @lv_cYear THEN record_count END ) AS RRC2019,
   SUM( CASE WHEN in_year eq @lv_lyear THEN record_count END ) AS RRC2018,
   SUM( CASE WHEN in_year eq @LV_2YEARSAGO THEN record_count END ) AS RRC2017
FROM entryTable
   GROUP BY type_name
   HAVING SUM( CASE WHEN in_year eq @lv_cYear THEN record_count END ) IN @ls_in_2019_range-select_options
   AND SUM( CASE WHEN in_year eq @lv_lyear THEN record_count END ) IN @ls_in_2018_range-select_options
   AND SUM( CASE WHEN in_year eq @LV_2YEARSAGO THEN record_count END ) IN @ls_in_2017_range-select_options
   ORDER BY (lv_order_by)
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @et_entityset.
```

If you try to run this the error "The parser produced the error: The expression that contains IN_YEAR is not a GROUP-BY expression" occurs.

If you replace "ORDER BY (lv_order_by)" with "ORDER BY RRC2019 DESCENDING, RRC2018 DESCENDING" it is working.

Comment: I think the problem is in your `GROUP BY` and not in `ORDER BY`. Is it a standard SAP table? Could you post a working example? Try also changing `GROUP BY type_name, in_year` to see if it works.

Comment: When you find such obvious issues, first search the ABAP documentation for any documented exception (I don't think there are any, the `ORDER BY` clause determined at run time should work as the `ORDER BY` clause defined statically), then search the SAP support whether there is a patch, if none then ask SAP support.

Comment: Also I am looking at your `SUM ... CASE` and it does not make any sense. It won't do what you want. I guess you want to have the sums for a particular year. In this form it will not work. You have to group by years (`in_year`) column.

Comment: Thanks for replies! @Jagger - The result structure looks like this: ** | Type | RRC2019 | RRC2018 | RRC2017 | **. After executing my sql (without order by) the table is filled with the different types and their summed up record counts for it. F.ex. **| TypeA | 25.123 | 35.233.111 | 972 |**. I use the group only for the type to do not have duplicates of types in the result set. When I now recheck the count sums via the se11 it seems to be correct.

Comment: If I would add *in_year* in the grouping clause it would cause one table entry for every type - in_year combination.

Comment: please see my answer. this is a bug. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used @Jagger's program and verified that it works in 7.50 and breaks starting from 7.51.

This should be a bug.

Update:
Please apply note [2753729](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2753729)

Answer (score 1):

I just allowed myself to prepare a compilable working example and it seems to work in contrary to what you have written. The only thing I changed is the location of `INTO TABLE` or (in your case) `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @et_entityset`.

The following example compiles without a problem and also does not generate any runtime exception.

```
REPORT YYY.

DATA:    lv_cYear      TYPE NUMC4,
         lv_lYear      TYPE NUMC4,
         lv_2YearsAgo  TYPE NUMC4,

         lv_order_by   TYPE string,
         ls_in_2019_range TYPE RANGE OF cosp-wtg001,
         ls_in_2018_range TYPE RANGE OF cosp-wtg001,
         ls_in_2017_range TYPE RANGE OF cosp-wtg001.

GET TIME.
lv_cYear = sy-datum+0(4).
LV_LYEAR = LV_CYEAR - 1.
LV_2YEARSAGO = LV_CYEAR - 2.

*later lv_order_by should be filled dynamically
lv_order_by = 'RRC2019 DESCENDING, RRC2018 DESCENDING'.

SELECT
   lednr AS type,
   SUM( CASE WHEN GJAHR eq @lv_cYear THEN wtg001 END ) AS RRC2019,
   SUM( CASE WHEN GJAHR eq @lv_lyear THEN wtg001 END ) AS RRC2018,
   SUM( CASE WHEN GJAHR eq @LV_2YEARSAGO THEN wtg001 END ) AS RRC2017
FROM cosp
   INTO TABLE @DATA(et_entityset)
   GROUP BY lednr
   HAVING SUM( CASE WHEN gjahr eq @lv_cYear THEN wtg001 END ) IN @ls_in_2019_range
   AND SUM( CASE WHEN gjahr eq @lv_lyear THEN wtg001 END ) IN @ls_in_2018_range
   AND SUM( CASE WHEN gjahr eq @LV_2YEARSAGO THEN wtg001 END ) IN @ls_in_2017_range
   ORDER BY (lv_order_by).

   BREAK-POINT.
```

Comment: Adding `INTO TABLE` after `FROM cosp` doesn't compile on my 7.52 systems : syntax error "The INTO/APPENDING clause must be at the end of the SELECT." The long text gives explanations about ABAP words not used in the statement above.

Comment: @SandraRossi Hi Sandra, I have it on 7.40. What you're telling me is a little bit worrying because it means that the code written with that version is not backward compatible. This is very strange.

Comment: The code I used is the one I have posted separately for the table SFLIGHT, I have the syntax error when I move `INTO TABLE @DATA(sflights)` right after `FROM sflight`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which compiles on all recent ABAP-based systems (use SAPBC_DATA_GENERATOR program to fill SFLIGHT table) :

```
DATA: dummy_price TYPE sflight-price.

SELECT-OPTIONS sum_y1 FOR dummy_price DEFAULT 0 TO 99999.
SELECT-OPTIONS sum_y2 FOR dummy_price DEFAULT 0 TO 99999.

SELECT  substring( fldate, 1, 4 ) AS year,
        MIN( fldate )             AS low,
        MAX( fldate )             AS high
      FROM sflight
      GROUP BY substring( fldate, 1, 4 )
      ORDER BY year
      INTO TABLE @DATA(y).

ASSERT lines( y ) >= 2.

SELECT carrid,
   SUM( CASE WHEN fldate BETWEEN @( y[ 1 ]-low ) AND @( y[ 1 ]-high ) THEN price END ) AS sum_year1,
   SUM( CASE WHEN fldate BETWEEN @( y[ 2 ]-low ) AND @( y[ 2 ]-high ) THEN price END ) AS sum_year2
FROM sflight
   GROUP BY carrid
   HAVING SUM( CASE WHEN fldate BETWEEN @( y[ 1 ]-low ) AND @( y[ 1 ]-high ) THEN price END ) IN @sum_y1[]
      AND SUM( CASE WHEN fldate BETWEEN @( y[ 2 ]-low ) AND @( y[ 2 ]-high ) THEN price END ) IN @sum_y2[]
   ORDER BY SUM_YEAR1 DESCENDING, SUM_YEAR2 DESCENDING " <=== this works
 """"ORDER BY ('SUM_YEAR1 DESCENDING, SUM_YEAR2 DESCENDING') " <=== uncomment for short dump
   INTO TABLE @DATA(sflights).

LOOP AT sflights ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<sflight>).
  WRITE : / <sflight>-carrid, <sflight>-sum_year1, <sflight>-sum_year2.
ENDLOOP.
```

On the following 2 systems, I reproduce the behavior (it works with static ORDER BY clause, short dump with dynamic ORDER BY clause) :

- developer edition 7.52 SP 1 with SYBASE ASE
- S/4HANA with ABAP 7.52 SP 0

No doubt there's a bug somewhere, but I couldn't find a SAP note to correct the issue. That would be better to open a ticket at SAP support.

Comment: I am glad you could reproduce my problem :) ! That is why I asked if the runtime handling is different when using dynamic sorting. If you Split the select from above: Define the selection above as a view (WITH +ABC AS ... ) . And then join it with another select: SELECT DISTINCT * carrid FROM sflight and join with the view on the carrid  - the same dynamic order should work now if you do it on the second select.

Comment: @ChristianR Unfortunately `WITH +abc AS ( SELECT ... ) SELECT * FROM +abc ORDER BY ('SUM_YEAR1 DESCENDING, SUM_YEAR2 DESCENDING')...` still produces the exact same short dump with the two ABAP versions I have mentioned.